# Gorilla jsonrpc getting empty response

Tags: go, rpc, json-rpc, gorilla

Why does my jsonrpc method return an empty response?

```
type Args struct {
  A, B int
}

type Response struct {
  sum int
  message string
}

type Arith int

func (t *Arith) Add(r *http.Request, args *Args, reply *Response) error {
  reply.sum = args.A + args.B
  reply.message = "Do math"

  // this does not work either

  //*reply = Response{
  //  sum : 12,
  //  message : "Do math",
  //}

  return nil
}
```

Request:

```
{"method":"Arith.Add","params":[{"A": 10, "B":2}], "id": 1}
```

Response:

```
{
  "result": {},
  "error": null,
  "id": 1
}
```

However, if I set the type of `reply` to `*string`, then this will work fine:

```
*reply = "Responding with strings works"
```

Response:

```
{
  "result": "Responding with strings works",
  "error": null,
  "id": 1
}
```

I'm using http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/rpc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Response` fields are unexported. The names should be uppercase:

```
type Response struct {
    Sum     int
    Message string
}
```